# The same derivative for very different functions

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Just a curiosity and request for a comment on this.

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(-2 \log  (u x-2))=-\frac{2 \left(x u'\right)}{u x-2}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}(-2 \log  (2-u x))=-\frac{2 \left(x u'\right)}{u x-2}
$$

What can be said about such results? Clearly there is nothing similar between $ux - 2$ and $2 - ux$, yet the equations are both the same. Checked with Mathematica and by simple manual computation. Maybe the differentiated functions can be derived one from another?

Comment: $ux - 2 = -(2 - ux)$; they're pretty closely related.

Comment: Note also that for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$, at most one of the two functions is defined.

Comment: @RobArthan Well, at most one is defined over any given interval, though which one is defined might change depending on the interval and $u$.

Comment: @RobArthan Never mind, I misread what you were saying. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to the fact that because:

$$
\frac{d}{dy} \log{y} = \frac{1}{y}
$$
then the chain rule gives us that:
$$
\frac{d}{dy}\log(-y) = -\frac{1}{-y} = \frac{1}{y} 
$$

However, for real $y$, at most one of $\log{y}$ and $\log(-y)$ is defined (because $\log$ is only defined for positive operands).